# How can I change processname of my python script on OpenBSD4.8

Tags: python, python-2.5, openbsd

I tried py-setproctitle and setproctitle. Both of them didn't work on OpenBSD.

Comment: A little bit of sample code you wrote would be good

Comment: `setproctitle.setproctitle("foo")` is enough to test that it doesn't work. This is probably a bug in py-setproctitle. setproctitle() works fine in 4.8 (tested in C).

Comment: @plundra , thats why I asked for sample code, its supposed to work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is [here](http://code.google.com/p/py-setproctitle/source/browse/setup.py?r=ae509066949dae2bf50420baa469b1678996273d#42)

In `setup.py` it tests if `setproctitle` is defined in `unistd.h`, although it is defined in `stdlib.h` on OpenBSD.

By checking in `stdlib.h` too (which is included later on - So no worries), everything works as expected.

Diff below:

```
--- setup.py~   Mon Jan  3 12:05:39 2011
+++ setup.py    Mon Jan  3 12:05:39 2011
@@ -39,7 +39,7 @@
     # Old BSD versions don't have setproctitle
     # TODO: not tested on an "old BSD"
     if 0 == os.spawnlp(os.P_WAIT, 'grep',
-            'grep', '-q', 'setproctitle', '/usr/include/unistd.h'):
+            'grep', '-q', 'setproctitle', '/usr/include/unistd.h', '/usr/include/stdlib.h'):
         define_macros['HAVE_SETPROCTITLE'] = 1
     else:
         define_macros['HAVE_PS_STRING'] = 1
```

The man-page from OpenBSD: [setproctitle(3)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=setproctitle) hints that it is in `stdlib.h`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works now. 
Is it possible to hide "python" from processlist? 


root      8590  0.0  0.3  1716  3716 p2  S+     4:15PM    0:00.05 python: OZKAN (python2.5)

Comment: @Ozkan Not without making changes in libc. Being able to freely change would make it very easy to hide unwanted software like backdoors etc. [setproctitle.c](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/lib/libc/gen/setproctitle.c?rev=1.11)

Comment: Thank you for the tip. The fix will be released in setproctitle 1.1.2.